# Navigation or mapping app to know if snow tires are needed for a given route in the United States

Tags: navigation

I'd like to drive from A to B in the United States. I'm looking for some app or webservice that can tell me, before starting to drive, whether snow tires or similar winter equipment are needed for the drive (vs. regular tires)? E.g., is there any navigation program that also incorporate weather information to advise whether snow tires or similar winter tire equipment are needed?

Any price, operating system, web browser or license is fine.

I found that Waze has a [‘Snow Warning’ tool](https://www.wmtw.com/article/want-to-avoid-snow-covered-roads-theres-an-app-for-that-waze-maine-traffic/30181221) that warns users about ice, unplowed roads:

[image]

but in practice it seems many snowed roads go unreported (likely because less used roads are more likely to be snow-covered).